# Formula for $\mathbb E_\nu[Y]$ when formula for $\mathbb P_\nu$ is given

Tags: measure-theory, probability-distributions

[image]

Given the formula for $\mathbb P_\nu[F]$, what is the formula for $\mathbb E_\nu[Y]$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ is a simple random variable (i.e. $X$ takes only finitely many values), then
\begin{equation*}
X = \sum_{i = 1}^{N} x_{i} 1_{\{X = x_{i}\}}
\end{equation*}
for some $\{x_{1},\dots,x_{N}\} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and then elementary properties of the Lebesgue integral yield
\begin{equation*}
\mathbb{E}_{\nu}(X) = \sum_{i = 1}^{N} x_{i} \mathbb{P}_{\nu}(\{X=x_{i}\}) = \sum_{i = 1}^{N} x_{i} \frac{\mathbb{E}(\exp(\langle \nu,Y\rangle) 1_{\{X=x_{i}\}})}{\mathbb{E}(\exp(\langle \nu,Y \rangle))} = \frac{\mathbb{E}(\exp(\langle \nu, Y \rangle) X)}{\mathbb{E}(\exp (\langle \nu,Y \rangle))}
\end{equation*}

If $X$ is a bounded random variable, then we can fix simple random variables $(X_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $X_{n} \to X$ uniformly and hence
\begin{equation*}
\mathbb{E}_{\nu}(X) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E}_{\nu}(X_{n}) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\mathbb{E}(\exp(\langle \nu, Y \rangle) X_{n})}{\mathbb{E}(\exp (\langle \nu,Y \rangle))} = \frac{\mathbb{E}(\exp(\langle \nu, Y \rangle) X)}{\mathbb{E}(\exp (\langle \nu,Y \rangle))}
\end{equation*}

Finally, the preceding discussion shows that a random variable $X$ is integrable with respect to $\mathbb{P}_{\nu}$ if and only if $\exp (\langle \nu, Y \rangle)X$ is integrable with respect to $\mathbb{P}$.  One then finds (e.g. using $X_{M} = X 1_{\{|X| \leq M\}}$ and arguing as in the previous paragraph) that
\begin{equation*}
\mathbb{E}_{\nu}(X) = \frac{\mathbb{E}(\exp(\langle \nu, Y \rangle) X)}{\mathbb{E}(\exp (\langle \nu,Y \rangle))}
\end{equation*}